# Incomplete cache storage

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I'm trying to cache thumbs (jpg) by `cache.addAll()` listed in an array fetched from server. So far so good.

The array has 365 thumbnail images listed, ~20MB total. Dumping the array in the console shows all thumbs listed.

Both Firefox and Chrome cache/app storage list only ~70-80 of the thumbs added to cache.

I tried setting `cache.maxEntries = 400` but this makes no difference.

Does this reflect a cache storage limit on # of items and/or storage size, or could there be other factor(s) causing this?

Comment: do you get any errors? btw where did you read about `cache.maxEntries` could not find it with an easy search.

Comment: It's an option in sw-toolbox (apparently all maxEntries is doing is forcing a cache rebuild, going by console debug entries).I'm adding a precache through the service worker, but caching the thumbs through user interaction in page javascript.

Comment: Whelp, it looks like the cache is fully populated going by `console.log(cachedRequests)` even if browsers fail to list everything. BTW I commented out the maxEntries thing with no apparent effect on cache functionality.